# How to show middle of the cell in rowspan data using DataTables RowsGroup plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, datatables

Here is my js code on jQuery ready function:

```
var data = responeText[1];
$('#table_id').DataTable({
    "lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"] ],
    "columns": [
        {
            name: 'first',
            title: 'Agent Name',
        },{
            name: 'second',
            title: 'Extension',
        },{
            name: 'third',
            title: 'Login Date',
        },{
            name: 'fourth',
            title: 'Login Time',
        },{
            name: 'fifth',
            title: 'Logout Date',
        },{
            name: 'sixth',
            title: 'Logout Time',
        }
    ],
    "data": data,
    "rowsGroup": [
        'first:name',
        'second:name',
    ],  
});
```

I use Datatable & Datatable RowsGroup plugin.
Rowgrouping data shows top of the rows, but 
I want to show rowgrouping data middle of the cell. How can I do that?